# Stack Exchange app for Windows Phone?

Tags: 8.0, 8.1, apps

Is there an app (official or otherwise) to access Stack Exchange communities for Windows Phone? Or does the mobile website work well?

Comment: yeah, the SE sites do have pretty good moblie views (especially compared to a lot of other sites) so I'll be sticking with IE as long as there's no official app (or something done by Rudy Huyn perhaps? :D).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are willing to work with some bugs, [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/6094/metro-stack-a-windows-phone-stack-exchange-app) might be an option. Personally, though, like @RowlandShaw, I use IE.

EDIT: The app I linked to has been officially released, so the bugs shouldn't be a glaring issue anymore.

Answer (score 2):

There is [an API](http://stackapps.com), but no official app - I just use IE.

If you do find issues using the site using the mobile browser, you can raise these on the [meta site](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/) which discusses issues about (using) this site.